# How to successfully send an image (png / jpg) via REST API as a HTTP Callout?

Tags: apex, integration

I am experimenting with sending a JSON payload for an HTTP POST callout to a microservice (similar to SendGrid). Upon a button click, the attachments from an email message in Salesforce are being processed by my logic to create a JSON object; which is then sent to an endpoint.

Using this approach works fine for many content types, like .html or .pdf files.

However, when I try to use this approach for image/png or image/jpg files, I receive a 'corrupted' error message.

The code I have so far is:

```
  calloutPayloadJson.writeStringField('subject', theMessageExt.Subject);
  calloutPayloadJson.writeStringField('body', theMessageExt.HtmlBody);
  calloutPayloadJson.writeStringField('contentType', 'text/html');
  if(attachments.size() > 0)
  {
        //build multipart attachment payload blob
  }
  calloutPayloadJson.writeEndObject();
  
  payLoad = calloutPayloadJson.getAsString();
  
  
  String boundaryString = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
  Http theHttpCallout = new Http();
  HttpRequest theHttpRequest = new HttpRequest();        
  theHttpRequest.setEndpoint(endPointURL);
  theHttpRequest.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundaryString);
  theHttpRequest.setMethod('POST');
  theHttpRequest.setTimeout(120000);
  Blob calloutBlob = blob.valueOf(callOutPayload);
  theHttpRequest.setBody(callOutPayload);
  if(!Test.isRunningTest())
  {
        theHttpRequest.setClientCertificateName(certname);
  }       
  HttpResponse calloutResponse = theHttpCallout.send(theHttpRequest);
```

The error message I get when trying to open up the .png file that I receive from the microservice, having de-serialized the .json and used it to send an email message to myself, reads:

*'Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.'*

I have tried to open the .png file up in Paint and I still receive the same error.

Even if I change the contentType on the 3rd line to 'image/png', the error remains.

I am unsure how I can serialize up png / jpg images here.

Comment: What will be the size of images? 6 MB or greater than 6 MB?

Comment: The images are below 6MB - I don't believe this is related at all to the heap size gov limits.